# Blender, Python Scripting Tutorials

Tags: python, blender

I already know some Python and got interested in extending Blender using Python scripts. Can anyone suggest me some good tutorials or books to learn this subject further? I'm already looking at Blender documentation, but I would like to learn some more because I'm a newbie when it comes to 3D modeling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Blender 2.5 Python 3.1 manual](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.5/Manual/Extensions/Python) has some good links to both basic internal tutorials for using Python scripts and some tutorials on other sites.

Bear in mind that this is Python 3.1, not 2.x, so you'd have to adjust accordingly.

You'll be using the Blender Python API (not so sure how well it's documented, but you should be fine). I'd familiarize myself with Blender and Python first (if you haven't already), then do some basic tutorials, and finally dive into the API.

Answer (score 3):

Blender 2.65 docs now have a tutorial on how to write an addon, This covers a lot of stuff related to general scripting too - not just addons.

http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_current/info_tutorial_addon.html

Answer (score 2):

I found the [Blender Wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Main_Page) very helpful in finding specific functions and procedures built in to Blender. To improve my Blender Python skills, I first decided to program a first person shooter. My first code for Blender was a mouselook script. This gave me most of the basics, and if I needed to, I could probably write a similar script in a matter of minutes now.

Also, a good idea is to look at other people's scripts and follow the logic.

There are many good tutorials for Blender and Python, but not too many for the crossover between them. Really the only way to get round that fact is to surf example scripts and websites. I found the Blender community is very supportive, so if you really get stuck on a small part, just ask.

I'm still a probable noob in the programming matter, but (with the exclusion of the node editor), I know my way around Blender pretty well, so if the worst comes to the worst, email/message me.